# Relatório RDLC em uma pasta interna do projeto?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

Criei um sistema com C# e WinForms e para criar meus relatórios criei uma pasta interna no projeto com o nome de `reports`, nesta pasta crio os RDLC para exibição no `ReportViewer` e funciona bem quando estou desenvolvendo.

Agora que está tudo pronto criei um instalador para meu sistema usando o `InstallShield Limited Edition` da Microsoft, o problema é que não consigo abrir meus relatórios pq a pasta é interna no projeto e ao abrir o caminho para o relatório não é encontrado.

Acredito que funcione em tempo de desenvolvimento pq a pasta existe e o executavel eh gerado na pasta `bin\Debug` eu apenas desço duas pastas e aponto para reports assim `@..\..\reports\MeuRelatorio.rdlc`. Mas como fazer isso quando o executavel armazena todas as pastas internas como quando instala ? Como resolver isso ?

**Para abrir o relatório em tempo de desenvolvimento faço assim.**

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"..\..\reports\RelContasPagar.rdlc";
```

**Exception**

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: Ocorreu um erro durante o processamento de relatórios local. ---> System.ApplicationException: A definição do relatório 'RelFluxoCaixa' não foi especificada ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\reports\RelFluxoCaixa.rdlc'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(PreviewItemContext itemContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(PreviewItemContext itemContext)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.Microsoft.Reporting.ILocalProcessingHost.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at ControleDeVendas.reports.ViewReport.geraRelFluxoCaixa()
   at ControleDeVendas.reports.ViewReport.executeTipoRelatorio()
   at ControleDeVendas.reports.ViewReport.ViewReport_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ControleDeVendas
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iguana%20Sistemas/Controle%20de%20Vendas/ControleDeVendas.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
NHibernate
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.4000
    Win32 Version: 4.0.4.4000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iguana%20Sistemas/Controle%20de%20Vendas/NHibernate.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
FluentNHibernate
    Assembly Version: 2.0.3.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.3.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Iguana%20Sistemas/Controle%20de%20Vendas/FluentNHibernate.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.GeneratedCode
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
MySql.Data
    Assembly Version: 6.9.8.0
    Win32 Version: 6.9.8.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MySql.Data/v4.0_6.9.8.0__c5687fc88969c44d/MySql.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Management
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Management/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Management.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms/11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources/11.0.0.0_pt_89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common/11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources
    Assembly Version: 11.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 11.0.3366.16 ((SQL11_SP1_RS_Dev12-RTM).130829-0516 )
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources/11.0.0.0_pt_89845dcd8080cc91/Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

**Pasta interna de relatórios.**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolvido. Bastou trocar o `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath` por `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource`.

ficando assim: `reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "ControleDeVendas.reports.RelFluxoCaixa.rdlc";`